# Ruby(HardWay(ex9)) << uninitialized constant PARAGRAPH

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm doing Ruby the Hard Way (ex9) -> http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html

Why can it not find the constant PARAGRAPH?

ERROR =>:

```
$ ruby ex9.rb
ex9.rb:9: uninitialized constant PARAGRAPH (NameError)
```

CODE (my input):

```
# Here's some new strange stuff, remember type it exactly.

days = "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
months = "Jan\n\Feb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug"

puts = "Here are the days: ", days
puts = "Here are the months: ", months

puts <<PARAGRAPH
Theres something going on here.
With the paragraph thing.
Well be able to type as much as we like.
Even four lines.
PARAGRAPH
```

NOTE: I modified the code in paragraph and stripped integers and possible statements like "if or "or" just to make sure I wasn't doing something else wrong. With the "right" code I get the following...

LESSON CODE ERROR =>:

```
ex9.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
     ^
```

LESSON CODE: (my input)

```
# Here's some new strange stuff, remember type it exactly.

days = "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
months = "Jan\n\Feb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug"

puts = "Here are the days: ", days
puts = "Here are the months: ", months

puts <<PARAGRAPH
There's something going on here.
With the PARAGRAPH thing
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
PARAGRAPH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Some Guy said, assigning `"Here are the days: ", days` to `puts` is your problem. When you hit the line `puts <<PARAGRAPH` the interpreter attempts to append `PARAGRAPH` to the array `puts` instead of generating the here doc, but of course `PARAGRAPH` is undefined.

Its kind of interesting, (though not super helpful) to note that you could actually still force it to work with the syntax

```
puts(<<PARAGRAPH)
Theres something going on here.
With the paragraph thing.
Well be able to type as much as we like.
Even four lines.
PARAGRAPH
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I totally didn't see the "=", it's amazing that I didn't notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts = "Here are the days: ", days
puts = "Here are the months: ", months
```

is your problem.  The = is probably not desired.